# When did "floored" become used to mean "surprised?"

Tags: verbs, slang, dates

My go-to resource, Etymology online, has plenty of information about "floor" as a noun, but not as a verb to mean "surprise" or even "knock over." I just want to know if it would be anachronistic to have a character from the 1920's use the term.

Comment: But Ety does say: "Sense of "puzzle, confound" is from 1830, a figurative use, from earlier sense of "knock down to the floor" "

Answer (score 2):

From the [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/71824?rskey=jcQ0oY&result=3#eid) **to floor**

In various figurative uses; colloquial:

> To confound, nonplus; to flabbergast, puzzle. In schoolboy slang, to
>   be or get floored: to grow confused, be at a loss, fail, break down.

As in:

> 1830   S. T. Coleridge Table-talk     The other day I was what you
>   would call floored by a Jew.

Early use of the figurative to floor predates a 1920 character, and use as such would appear to be appropriate and grammatical.